# Can't get EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification after connection

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, bluetooth, mfi

I can detect my MFI compliant chip in the list of Bluetooth devices (from my iphone 5C)  but once the connection is established I do not get the notification `EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification` ... I use the demo EADemo proposed by Apple. Can you help me about that issue ?

I have also test it with `showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter`, and I get

> BTM: connection to service 0x00000080 on device "BRAIN_WT12_2" 00:07:80:99:EE:4C succeeded.

So, why I don't get any `EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification` notifications?

Here is my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:nil completion:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_accessoryDidConnect:) name:EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_accessoryDidDisconnect:) name:EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification object:nil];
[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] registerForLocalNotifications];
```

...

Comment: Do you get the `didDisconnectNotification`? Where's your code for registering the notifications?

Comment: My code code for registering the notifications is just before the [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver... lines. And no, I don't get the didDisconnectNotification ...

Comment: @Geoffroy How did you managed to call it? I am also facing the same issue.